# A discrete optimization (integer programming) problem

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, dynamic-programming, programming

This is a assignment from a class.

Assume I have $N$ empty rooms which **each** has $X$ apples and $Y$ oranges. There are $15$ different kinds of monkeys with different demands of apples $x_i$ and oranges $y_i$. I want to assign these monkeys (each kind with $z_i$ monkeys) to the rooms and minimize the number of the room needed?

At first I thought it was a dynamic programming, but things are not so easy. Could anyone provide some ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is easy to formulate this problem as an integer program.

Comment: @prubin Thanks. I have already formulated this problem as an $l_0$ norm program